# How to start FragmentTransaction within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My `FragmentA` contains a `ListView`. My `FragmentB` contains the details of each item. How do I begin a transaction from FragmentA's `onItemClickListener()`.

```
Fragment newFragment = EntryFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction
        .replace(containerId, newFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

on the creation of `FragmentA` I pass the `R.id.container` to `containerId`. When the transaction is called, It throws an error "No view found for id 0x0somehexnumber"

Comment: IMHO, you should have FragmentA call a method on its hosting activity, perhaps via the contract pattern, and have the activity respond to the UI event. Showing FragmentB may not be the right answer for all screen sizes and such, and the fragments should be generally oblivious to screen size. Beyond that, it would appear that you perhaps have the wrong `containerId`, as the error message indicates that there is nothing with that value.

Comment: Do you know that id belong to which view? You can check the view id by looking at gen/com.example.packagename/R.java

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to pass the container ID.**

Simply use `R.id.your_containerlayout`.

for the `replace(...)` parameter. Also, calling this line will be sufficient:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

If you are within a support-Fragment, this will get you the **SupportFragmentManager**.